# EC2 security group settings are not allowing SSH access

Tags: networking, ssh, amazon-ec2, cloud-computing

So when I open port 22 and 80 in the default security group I'm not able to ping the domain.  I've opened TCP, UDP, and ICMP to all and now it works but of course I need to find another solution.  What should I be opening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ping uses the ICMP protocol so you need to provide a custom ICMP rule in your security group to allow it through.

On the security group inbound tab select `Custom ICMP Rule` then for type select `Echo Request`. If you want to restrict this to a particular IP address/network then complete the source field. Click `Add Rule` then `Apply Rule Changes`.

These are the security group rules I have on a centos instance

- ICMP

  - `ALL sg-08e86d61 (default)`
  - `Echo Request  0.0.0.0/0`
- TCP

  - `0 - 65535    sg-08e86d61 (default)`
  - `22 (SSH)  0.0.0.0/0`
  - `80 (HTTP) 0.0.0.0/0`
- UDP

  - `0 - 65535    sg-08e86d61 (default)`